# Parse a specific string from a converted bytes string

Tags: c#, .net, text-parsing

I have URL file which is being returned in bytes, I am reading these bytes using stream reader to get the data in the file. Converted .URL data as below.

```
[DEFAULT]
BASEURL=http://someUrl.com/employee-view/index.aspx?id=123
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://someUrl.com/employee-view/index.aspx?id=123\0
```

I want to parse just the base URL string -- `http://someUrl.com/employee-view/index.aspx?id=123`

I am able to extract the baseUrl string using the following code. But I am looking for a better way.

```
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(docStream.DocumentBytes)))
   {
       string f = reader.ReadToEnd();

       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f))
       {
          string[] arr = f.Split('=');
          StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(arr[1]);
          var a = arr[2].Split('[')[0];
          url.Append(SR.Common.Equals).Append(a);

          string finalUrl = url.ToString();

      } 
   }
```

All I need is the base URL string -- `http://someUrl.com/employee-view/index.aspx?id=123`

Comment: Please define "a better way". Faster? More robust? Better code readability?

Comment: You might want to split it into lines of text first, and then process each line. As written now, your `finalUrl` will probably have the `\n` or `\r\n` of the source file in it.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you mean - "all I need is the base URL string." Is that different from what you already have? It sounds like you have a URL and you're trying to get just part of it. You're showing us which part you want to end up with but not what you're starting with.

Comment: Your data is laid out like some .ini files I have used in recent projects. You could use an old function called GetPrivateProfileString.

Comment: dymanoid & Scott Hannen, i looking for a faster and cleaner code to extract just the url from -- [DEFAULT]
BASEURL=http://someUrl.com/employee-view/index.aspx?id=123
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://someUrl.com/employee-view/index.aspx?id=123\0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, If you mean a smaller code

Using Linq:

```
finalUrl = f.Replace("\0","").Replace("\r","")
    .Split('\n')
    .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.StartsWith("URL"))
    .Split(new[] {'='},2)[1];
```

Using Regex:

```
finalUrl = Regex.Match(f,@"(?<=URL\=).+").Value;
```

Comment: Regex solution gave exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!